# Node.js кириллица

Tags: javascript, node.js

Изучаю Node.js
По учебнику предложили сделать простой консольный переводчик.
API Яндекса закрыто для хохла, API google.translate платный. Узнал про [альтернативу](https://ctrlq.org/code/19909-google-translate-api) для расширений google, и этот способ действительно работает. Но если попытаться перевести
**с русского** выдаёт непонятный мне JSON:

```
[[["РїСЂРёРІРµС‚","РїСЂРёРІРµС‚",null,null,0]],null,"ru"]
```

И что самое непонятное, текстовый файл, в котором приходит ответ редакторами открывается нормально и русская речь читается, но вот внутри программы это кракозябры.
И всё нормально читалось если переводить **на русский** либо с английского на английский.

```js
var request = require('request');

request('https://translate.googleapis.com'
   +'/translate_a/single?'
   +'client=gtx&sl=ru&tl=en&dt=t&q='
   +encodeURI('привет'), showTranslate);

function showTranslate (error, response, body) { console.log(body) };
```

Comment: это из за кодировки консоли.Node ожидает от неё вывода в кодировке UTF-8, тогда как в русифицированной системе Windows выводят текст в кодировке CP866.

Comment: Кстати консоль windows овская ? Использование UTF-8 в cmd.exe http://anvarichn.livejournal.com/43752.html

Comment: Спасибо за статью о кодировке в cmd. Но что мне делать с Node я не понимаю. Даже сделав всё по инструкции, в консоли выводятся непонятные символы, да и сама программа тоже их видит. Дело не в консоли.